# Creating two dimension table that width and height is known after constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, dictionary

The basic idea is that player moves on map which is created from file. width and height is known first read in construcutor. table should be avabile on whole class and also to the player (so inheritation i assume).

```
class map{
  public:
      int height,width;
      int coords[height][width];//I want this to be created after constructor but avalible in whole class and inherited by player   
    map(string filename)
    {
        height=0;
        width=0;
        ifstream myfile("input.txt");
        while(lines)
        {
            height++;
        }
        //width=something;
    filltable();
    }
};
class player:public map{
    public:
        int x,y;
        player(){
        x=mapa.width/2;
        y=mapa.height/2;
        }
};
```

Comment: How do you know the width from your file ?

Comment: I wanted to make this code as simple as possible so i deleted that part. but f.ex if i got file that has got 1010010 and few rows of other data i can know the width of it and create the rectangualr map.

Answer (score -2):

`int coords[height][width]` will not work in C++. You need variable lentgh matrix, and this is represented in Standard C++ as a vector of vectors. Other libraries provide matrix as a more usefull class.

Comment: vector of vectors may be very inefficient by means of cache misses because of non contiguously stored data. Better to use a single vector, and map rows and columns using the appropriate offsets.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Fair enough. I doubt author worries about cache misses at this point, and I believe, OP would benefit from code simplicity more than loose on cache missess.

Comment: Then you should at least show them, how to fix their current code using your proposal. Also, that statement _" and this is represented in Standard C++ as a vector of vectors"_ simply isn't true in general.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what I was trying to say is that Standard C++ library (as well as C) has not concept of a matrix, and  array of arrays in C is mapped to vector of vectors in C++.

Comment: And I stated, that's not true in general, that it's always needed to be implemented as such. Vector of vectors is just a naive low hanging fruit approach, that misses a number of pitfalls you're likely to fall in.

Comment: Can someone show me a fix or just a different alproach to this dilleama cause ive got no idea how i should write it to be oop nicely. to have map,player and in map read map file

Comment: with vector it would be simpler but it's not "nice,simple,clear" solution as it was supposed to be